# unable to import data from CSV into PipelineDB

Tags: csv, import, pipelinedb

I have successfully installed PipelineDB. I want to import data into the DB from a CSV file. I have searched a lot but could not find a solution for this. How do I do this?

Comment: This question is related to pipelinedb not pipeline. Tags must be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data into a PipelineDB stream like so:

```
COPY stream (x, y, z) FROM '/some/file.csv'
```

See the [PipelineDB documentation](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/streams.html#copy) for more information.